# Pourquoi « le Grand Paris/Londres/Bruxelles » et non « la Grande … » ?

Tags: genre, noms-propres, toponymes

Dans chaque cas on fait référence à une ville, c'est-à-dire quelque chose féminine. J'aurais donc cru « grande » au féminin plus correct, comme on dit « une belle Citroën ».

Comment: Qu'est ce qui vous amène à penser que les noms propres de villes seraient de genre féminin ? En pratique, il semble que l'option standard soit le masculin, y compris pour des noms comme La Rochelle. *Le La Rochelle de mon enfance a disparu.*

Answer (score 17):

La réponse courte est : « tu fais ce que tu veux !»

La [réponse](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/vehicule-voie_espace_public.html) longue est celle de  de Lacroux dans son excellent ouvrage [Orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/) (disponible gratuitement !) :

> Déterminées occasionnellement par un article défini, les villes adoptent de préférence le masculin. Certains adjectifs antéposés (grand, vieux) accentuent cette tendance.
>
> Londres est belle (ou beau) sous le brouillard, le Londres de Dickens est moins vert que la Normandie de Maupassant, le Grand Londres a été liquidé par Margaret Thatcher.
>
> Marseille est belle sous le soleil, il regrette le Marseille des années trente, Bruxelles est belle (ou beau) sous la drache.
>
> Le vieux Bruxelles a été liquidé par les spéculateurs et les architectes.
>   Alger est blanc sous le soleil, aussi l’appelle-t-on Alger la Blanche.
>   Précédées de tout, toutes les villes renoncent au féminin, y compris celles dont le nom inclut un article défini féminin : tout La Rochelle est saisi d’allégresse, toute la ville en parle.
>
> Remarque. — « Tout » signifie ici « toute la population de » et non « l’ensemble de la ville de ». C’est donc à tort que l’on écrit parfois : [« Tout Londres est en flammes. »]
>   Tout Paris est dans les rues, le Tout-Paris.
>
> Quelques villes italiennes sont très attachées à leur genre. Mais il y a des limites à tout :
>
> — la Florence des Médicis, la Venise des doges, tout Venise est enrhumé ;
>
> — la Rome des papes, Rome est belle sous les Césars, on circule mal dans le Grand Rome, tout Rome est à Ostie.
>
> Lorsque le nom d’une ville est employé pour désigner une équipe ou un club sportifs, le masculin est de rigueur (même s’il s’agit d’une équipe féminine) : La Rochelle a été battu au Havre ; Marseille, affaibli, renonce à rencontrer Valenciennes.

Oui, c'est le bazar. Fiez-vous à votre instinct !

---

Si tu cherches une réponse générale et au cas par cas pour les villes, le même lien te renseignera !

> Quiconque a soif de certitude ne se désaltérera pas ici. Le genre des villes est un des hauts lieux de la liberté onomastique. Hormis celles dont le nom contient un article (singulier), les villes ne se laissent pas facilement attribuer un genre immuable.
>
> Sont a priori des noms masculins : Le Caire, Le Havre, Le Vésinet.
>   Sont a priori des noms féminins : La Ferté-Alais, La Havane, La Nouvelle-Orléans.
>
> Lorsqu’un article pluriel précède un « nom commun courant », le genre est aisé à deviner : Les Sables-d’Olonne sont situés sur l’Atlantique.
>   Les « saints » sont d’un grand secours : Saint-Étienne et Sainte-Menehould ne sont pas du même genre.
>
> Pour les milliers de villes dont le nom ne contient aucun élément d’un genre clairement identifiable, on suggère parfois de se fier à la dernière syllabe, à la rime. Syllabe muette, le nom a de grandes chances d’être féminin ; syllabe sonore, le nom a de grandes chances d’être masculin. Certains auteurs présentent comme une vieille règle française l’attribution du féminin aux noms de villes se terminant par une voyelle, du masculin à ceux qui se terminent par une consonne. Ces deux « règles » sont souvent contradictoires : Londres (syllabe muette, consonne), Marseille (syllabe muette, voyelle).
>
> Même si elles peuvent aider parfois à « se faire une idée », il est préférable de les considérer toutes les deux avec circonspection ou, mieux, de les oublier.
>
> Pour deux raisons :
>
> — Si l’on tente de vérifier leur pertinence avec des exemples indiscutables, on obtient ceci : Le Caire, Le Havre, Les Sables-d’Olonne, Saint-Étienne (voyelle, syllabe muette… masculin) ; La Ferté-Alais, La Nouvelle-Orléans, Sainte-Menehould (consonne, syllabe sonore… féminin) ;
>
> — Selon les circonstances (syntaxe et niveau de langue, registre), les noms de villes peuvent être soit masculins, soit féminins…

Désolé pour le copier-coller, mais je ne voyais pas comment synthétiser.

(J'ai un doute sur la clause ND de la licence Creative Commons. Quelqu'un peut me renseigner ?)

Comment: [CC-NC-ND](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/fr/) : Tel que je le comprends, on peut citer mais pas modifier. Pas utilisable dans un context commercial, non modifiable, attribution obligatoire. Les citations étant un copier-coller, toutes les clauses me semblent respectées.

Answer (score 3):

Essentiellement dans le même sens que l'excellent contenu présenté en [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14535), quelques *observations* au sujet du genre des *noms propres de lieux* présentées dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*), au §472<sup>1</sup> :

---

Après avoir introduit l'idée que le genre des *noms géographiques* relève de l'« *arbitraire* » et donc que « *ni l'étymologie ni la forme ni le sens ne sont déterminants.* », on traite spécifiquement des *noms de villes* et on note :

- Le masculin dans l'usage parlé, et souvent le féminin à l'écrit, surtout
  littéraire. On dit parfois que seuls les noms se terminant en « *e* » seront féminins. Il s'agit d'usages, et il y a beaucoup d'exemples de choix différents (« *Lyon,
  Marseille, Bordeaux, insurgées.* », France ; « *La blanche Navarin* », Hugo)
- Le féminin est naturel quand le nom incorpore l'*article* au féminin
  (*la*)
- Le masculin l'emporte dans certains cas types quand le nom est :

  - Précédé de *vieux/nouveau/grand* pour les quartiers ou l'extension d'une ville
  - Précédé de *tout* (l'[*élite*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/Tout-Paris/78786?q=paris#77850))
  - Employé par *métonymie* pour l'évènement/l'équipe au sport, ou pour désigner les institutions (supra)nationales (« *Bruxelles est concerné par la question de* [...] », le Monde)

Enfin on dit que les noms des villes étaient au féminin « jadis » (on donne par ex. « *Des joiaux de richesse toute Paris resplent* », *Berte*, ed. [*Holmes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q78tAAAAIAAJ&q=%22toute%20Paris%20resplent%22%20ed.%20Holmes&dq=%22toute%20Paris%20resplent%22%20ed.%20Holmes&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y), Adenet le Roi, au 13<sup>e</sup>; « *Fut Lanchon destruite* », [*Ly myreur des histors*](https://books.google.com/books?id=uXcyENtplD8C&lpg=PA235&dq=%22fut%20lanchon%20destruite%22&hl=fr&pg=PA235#v=onepage&q=%22fut%20lanchon%20destruite%22&f=false), d'Outremeuse, au 14<sup>e</sup>).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Il ne s'agit que de grandes lignes provenant des observations. Voir aussi, *BDL* ([genre](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1608) ; [grand + ville](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5218)), [*CTQ*](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/normes-procedures/regles-ecriture/accord-noms-villes.html), [*CNIG*](http://archives.cnig.gouv.fr/Front/index.php?RID=20).</sub>