# Pourquoi dit-on « vieux Nice » au lieu de « vieille Nice »

Tags: adjectifs, genre, géographie, toponymes

Pourquoi dit-on :

> « vieux Nice » (masculin)

au lieu de :

> « vieille Nice » (feminin)

Nice est une ville, et pour autres villes j'ai vu qu'on utilise l'adjectif feminin « vieille » ?

Comment: cf [cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14534/pourquoi-le-grand-paris-londres-bruxelles-et-non-la-grande/14535#14535)

Comment: Tu dis « pour d'autres villes », peux-tu donner des exemples ?

Comment: @Laure: je pense d'avoir vu un tel signe à Cannes... et dans autres villes en Côte d'Azur.

Comment: For me, this question goes a bit deeper (or at least has the potential to go deeper) than simply asking why some cities are masculine and some feminine and therefore, imo, it shouldn't be closed. I see it as asking why some parts/quarters of some cities have fixed, usually hyphenated names using the masculine (like Vieux-Nice or Vieux-Lille) even though the same speaker might prefer/choose to use the feminine when referring to that city elsewhere (even in the same sentence): “En general, Nice n’est pas trop chère, mais le Vieux-Nice devient cher, je trouve.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parce que *Vieux Nice* ne veut pas dire *la vieille ville de Nice*, mais plutôt *le vieux centre de Nice*.

Comment: C'est une question d'usage de mettre les noms de villes au masculin et ça n'a pas de rapport avec un usage sous-entendu du mot « centre ». L'usage est de dire aussi « Le Nice de mon enfance  », « Le Paris du 20e siècle ? etc...

Comment: C'est vrai, mais dans ce cas, *Vieux Nice* n'égale pas *le Nice* - il s'agit uniquement du centre.

Comment: Centre et vieille partie d'une ville sont deux choses distinctes. Je ne connais pas Nice - peut-être que le vieux Nice couvre le centre de la ville, mais ce serait une coïncidence, la vielle partie d'une ville est souvent bien plus petite en superficie que ce qu'on appelle le « centre ville ».

Comment: *Centre historique*, synonyme du *vieux centre*, ne veut pas dire *le centre exact de la ville* ni *le centre-ville*.

Comment: For Lille, maybe the masculine comes from “Vieux-[**quartier de**] Lille,” but for my favorite cheese, I like to think it’s derived from Vieux-[fromage/Gris de] Lille!  @Laure