# Pourquoi le participe passé « devenu » doit-il s'accorder au féminin singulier ?

Tags: accord, genre, noms-propres, toponymes

> Narzair semble être **devenue** une ville dangereuse.

Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer pourquoi il faut que le participe passé « devenu » s'accorde avec le nom féminin singulier « une ville » dans cette phrase ?

Moi qui croyais que le sujet « Narzair {masculin} » était celui avec lequel « devenu » doit s'accorder, pas avec « une ville ». Est-ce simplement parce que « Narzair » équivaut à « une ville dangereuse », après tout ?

Comment: Si Narzair est une ville, alors c'est un nom feminin.

Comment: [Ce lien](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14534/pourquoi-le-grand-paris-londres-bruxelles-et-non-la-grande/14535#14535) t'aidera peut-être !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si *Narzair* est un nom de ville, le genre est celui de l'objet que le mot représente.

> (1) Narzair semble être devenue une ville dangereuse.
>   (2) Narzair semble être devenu un lieu dangereux.

(1) Narzair est une ville.
(2) Narzair est un lieu.

> [Paris est devenue une ville cyclable...](http://www.apur.org/etude/paris-ville-metropole-cyclable)
>   [Paris est devenu un lieu privilégié de flânerie pour ses habitants, les provinciaux et les étrangers](https://books.google.fr/books?id=BDzOLM0mnTcC&pg=PP27&lpg=PP27&dq=%22Paris%20est%20devenu%20un%20lieu%22&source=bl&ots=tPfk2X_3YD&sig=3BoRENTtAXF5n389_DLnLWxvM1o&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYgdXn2uPPAhWDOhoKHduxBO0Q6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=%22Paris%20est%20devenu%20un%20lieu%22&f=false).

Mais :

> Marie est devenue une adulte agréable.
>   Marie est devenue un être agréable.

Qu'elle soit considérée comme une adulte ou comme un être, Marie n'en reste pas moins de sexe féminin.

Comment: I have never learnt French Grammar systematically from grammar books and such, alors cette règle m'a échappé! I was tempted to say "échapper", while I'm at it. (ha-ha) Merci.

Comment: @LUNA I don't think there's a grammar rule to cover the point of your question. It's a question of usage around city names, and just knowing that city names are usually neither masculine nor feminine probably doesn't cover every case. I think it's very tricky for non French natives (and even for natives it's probably not that obvious).

Comment: C'est une règle de devoir accorder au masculin si le COD est masculin ? Mettre au féminin même quand un parle d'un lieu ne me choquerait pas.

Comment: Ah, how true! The "il" of "faut-il" cannot work the same way as the "il" of "doit-il" does, since the "il" of "faut-il" does NOT refer to the phrase "le participe passé". Merci de me l'avoir remarqué. :)

Comment: I should have said: "Pourquoi faut-il accorder le participe passé « devenu » au féminin singulier ?"

Comment: @LUNA  Yes, correct.