# Genre des villes

Tags: genre, noms-propres, toponymes

On dit [« Paris la belle »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_la_belle) mais [« le Vieux-Québec »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieux-Qu%C3%A9bec) (et encore [« C'est si beau, Paris »](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Daniel_Lavoie:Un_Jour_Ce_Sera_Ton_Tour), mais je comprends que l'emploi du démonstratif pourrait expliquer ce dernier).

Do city names:

1. All have the same default gender? If so, which of the above is an exception?
2. Have an inherent gender that differs from city to city?

   - A more likely variant: Have an inherent gender if an expression like the above has appeared and become fixed, a status presumably only a few of the most famous cities enjoy?
3. Take a gender at the time of utterance, as determined by whether a butterfly has flapped its wings in China?
4. Obey some combination of the above or any other pattern you might suggest?

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, that makes sense. However, the answer to my question is actually contained in [the further-back thread referred to](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14534/pourquoi-le-grand-paris-londres-bruxelles-et-non-la-grande) in the one you chose. (The one chosen contains an answer claiming it's an underlying *ville* vs. *centre*, whereas the thread from further back has a great detailed answer on the pattern/lack thereof.) I can't seem to edit the duplicate notice accordingly; can you, or should I reopen and reclose? Or ignore and let people follow further back?

Comment: I think your question is closest to that one. But if you think it's best, I can edit the duplicate link.

Comment: @Gilles The questions seem about equally related to me, but the other answer seems like the one I'd want to read if I stumbled on this question. Please do, and thanks!

Comment: Turns out I can edit the links to have both (it's a fairly new feature), so I did that.